# Select a web window prompt using node server crawler

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web-crawler

I'm trying to access a webpage with my Node Crawler (https://github.com/bda-research/node-crawler), but I need to enter credentials into a window prompt.

When trying to access the page with the crawler, I'm send directly to the 401 page (where I'm directed to in Chrome if I cancel the prompt).

```
var Crawler = require("crawler");    

var c = new Crawler({
  callback: function (error, res, done) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      var $ = res.$;
      // $ is Cheerio by default
      //  a lean implementation of core jQuery designed specifically for the server
      console.log($("title").text()); // logs 401
    }
    done();
  }
});

c.queue(url);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Show your code and what you've tried. Are you using an npm package to do this? Hard to help without more information

Comment: hows that, @abney317?

Comment: If you need to interact with a page your best bet is to use [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/).

Answer (score 0):

The documentation references another library that has the options

> You can pass these options to the Crawler() constructor if you want them to be global or as items in the queue() calls if you want them to be specific to that item (overwriting global options)
>
> This options list is a strict superset of [mikeal's request options](https://github.com/mikeal/request#requestoptions-callback) and will be directly passed to the request() method.

That documentation shows an `auth` option

> auth - a hash containing values user || username, pass || password, and sendImmediately (optional). See documentation above.

Looks like something like this will work although I didn't test

```
var Crawler = require("crawler");    

var c = new Crawler({
  auth: {
    user: 'username',
    pass: 'password'
  },
  callback: function (error, res, done) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      var $ = res.$;
      // $ is Cheerio by default
      //  a lean implementation of core jQuery designed specifically for the server
      console.log($("title").text()); // logs 401
    }
    done();
  }
});

c.queue(url);
```